# How to redirect console output to a text file

Tags: perl, command-line

I am executing a Perl program. Whatever is being printed on my console, I want to redirect
that to a text file.

Comment: Why not just do it from the command line: `perl -w my_program.pl > output.txt` ?

Comment: @PaulR I can't +1 enough. Post that as an answer - it is the correct way to do it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/387702/how-can-i-hook-into-perls-print

Comment: @Polynomial: OK - it seemed too trivial to post as an answer, but I've done it anyway, for future reference.

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907593/how-can-i-redirect-standard-output-to-a-file-in-perl

Comment: What's your operating system?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The preferred method for this is to handle redirection via the command line, e.g.

```
perl -w my_program.pl > my_output.txt
```

If you want to also include stderr output then you can do this (assuming your shell is bash):

```
perl -w my_program.pl &> my_output.txt
```

Comment: OK - see above edit - also take some time to learn command line basics for Linux etc.

Comment: Thanks.... in file i have used open STDERR, '>output.txt'; close STDERR; its working....

Comment: For future reference note that it's generally better to do the redirection on the command line - that way you don't need to modify your Perl code, and you can re-use it in different contexts without any changes.

Answer (score 11):

In the CLI you can use `>`, like this:

```
perl <args> script_name.pl > path_to_your_file
```

If you want to do this inside the perl script, add this code before you print anything:

```
open(FH, '>', 'path_to_your_file') or die "cannot open file";
select FH;
# ...
# ... everything you print should be redirected to your file
# ...
close FH;  # in the end
```

Comment: well, if you have explicit prints to different filehandles, than you should follow the CLI way as advised by Paul R and this question probably should be tagged as `bash` or similar because it has little to do with Perl itself

Answer (score 6):

On Unix, to capture everything that goes to your terminal, you want to redirect both the standard output and the standard error.

With bash, the command resembles

```
$ ./my-perl-program arg1 arg2 argn > output.txt 2>&1
```

The C shell, `csh` derivatives such as `tcsh`, and newer versions of bash understand

```
$ ./my-perl-program arg1 arg2 argn >& output.txt
```

to mean the same thing.

The syntax for the command shell on Windows resembles Bourne shell's.

```
C:\> my-perl-program.pl args 1> output.txt 2>&1
```

To set up this redirection in your Perl code, add

```
open STDOUT, ">", "output.txt" or die "$0: open: $!";
open STDERR, ">&STDOUT"        or die "$0: dup: $!";
```

to the beginning of your program’s executable statements.

Answer (score 3):

If you want your output to be printed on console as well as logs then append this line to you code (e.g. before any print statements)

```
open (STDOUT, "| tee -ai logs.txt");
print "It Works!";
```

After last print in your script

```
close (STDOUT);
```

For error messages only,

```
open (STDERR, "| tee -ai errorlogs.txt");
```