# How to address a perl program to write it's output to a file?

Tags: perl

I want to analyse my summaries using ROUGE. So far i have written a perl script to run ROUGE on the command line, this is what I have so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use Cwd;
$curdir=getcwd;
$ROUGE="/ROUGE-1.5.5.pl";
chdir("sample-test");
$cmd="$ROUGE -e /data -c 95 -2 -1 -U -r 1000 -n 4 -w 1.2 -a DUC2002ROUGE.in.26.spl.xm> /sample-output/salam.out";
print $cmd,"\n";
system($cmd);
chdir($curdir);
```

However I get this error:

> the system can't find the specified path

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you want to evaluate the summerization using rouge in windows.I recommend you to use an `ubuntu` version of linux and install the rouge and use this command to get your output:

I mean save this file as a perl file and execute this file in terminal of linux

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl -w
use Cwd;
$curdir=getcwd;
$ROUGE="../ROUGE-1.5.5.pl";
chdir("sample-test");
$cmd="$ROUGE -e ../data -c 95 -2 -1 -U -r 1000 -n 4 -w 1.2 -a ROUGE-test.xml > ../sample-output/ROUGE-test-c95-2-1-U-r1000-n4-w1.2-a.out";
print $cmd,"\n";
system($cmd);
$cmd="$ROUGE -e ../data -c 95 -2 -1 -U -r 1000 -n 4 -w 1.2 -a -m ROUGE-test.xml > ../sample-output/ROUGE-test-c95-2-1-U-r1000-n4-w1.2-a-m.out";
print $cmd,"\n";
system($cmd);
$cmd="$ROUGE -e ../data -c 95 -2 -1 -U -r 1000 -n 4 -w 1.2 -a -m -s ROUGE-test.xml > ../sample-output/ROUGE-test-c95-2-1-U-r1000-n4-w1.2-a-m-s.out";
print $cmd,"\n";
system($cmd);
$cmd="$ROUGE -e ../data -c 95 -2 -1 -U -r 1000 -n 4 -w 1.2 -l 10 -a ROUGE-test.xml > ../sample-output/ROUGE-test-c95-2-1-U-r1000-n4-w1.2-l10-a.out";
print $cmd,"\n";
system($cmd);
$cmd="$ROUGE -e ../data -c 95 -2 -1 -U -r 1000 -n 4 -w 1.2 -l 10 -a -m ROUGE-test.xml > ../sample-output/ROUGE-test-c95-2-1-U-r1000-n4-w1.2-l10-a-m.out";
print $cmd,"\n";
system($cmd);
$cmd="$ROUGE -e ../data -c 95 -2 -1 -U -r 1000 -n 4 -w 1.2 -l 10 -a -m -s ROUGE-test.xml > ../sample-output/ROUGE-test-c95-2-1-U-r1000-n4-w1.2-l10-a-m-s.out";
print $cmd,"\n";
system($cmd);
$cmd="$ROUGE -e ../data -c 95 -2 -1 -U -r 1000 -n 4 -w 1.2 -b 75 -a ROUGE-test.xml > ../sample-output/ROUGE-test-c95-2-1-U-r1000-n4-w1.2-b75-a.out";
print $cmd,"\n";
system($cmd);
$cmd="$ROUGE -e ../data -c 95 -2 -1 -U -r 1000 -n 4 -w 1.2 -b 75 -a -m ROUGE-test.xml > ../sample-output/ROUGE-test-c95-2-1-U-r1000-n4-w1.2-b75-a-m.out";
print $cmd,"\n";
system($cmd);
$cmd="$ROUGE -e ../data -c 95 -2 -1 -U -r 1000 -n 4 -w 1.2 -b 75 -a -m -s ROUGE-test.xml > ../sample-output/ROUGE-test-c95-2-1-U-r1000-n4-w1.2-b75-a-m-s.out";
print $cmd,"\n";
system($cmd);
$cmd="$ROUGE -e ../data -3 HM -z SIMPLE DUC2002-BE-F.in.26.lst 26 > ../sample-output/DUC2002-BE-F.in.26.lst.out";
print $cmd,"\n";
system($cmd);
$cmd="$ROUGE -e ../data -3 HM DUC2002-BE-F.in.26.simple.xml 26 > ../sample-output/DUC2002-BE-F.in.26.simple.out";
print $cmd,"\n";
system($cmd);
$cmd="$ROUGE -e ../data -3 HM -z SIMPLE DUC2002-BE-L.in.26.lst 26 > ../sample-output/DUC2002-BE-L.in.26.lst.out";
print $cmd,"\n";
system($cmd);
$cmd="$ROUGE -e ../data -3 HM DUC2002-BE-L.in.26.simple.xml 26 > ../sample-output/DUC2002-BE-L.in.26.simple.out";
print $cmd,"\n";
system($cmd);
$cmd="$ROUGE -e ../data -n 4 -z SPL DUC2002-ROUGE.in.26.spl.lst 26 > ../sample-output/DUC2002-ROUGE.in.26.spl.lst.out";
print $cmd,"\n";
system($cmd);
$cmd="$ROUGE -e ../data -n 4 DUC2002-ROUGE.in.26.spl.xml 26 > ../sample-output/DUC2002-ROUGE.in.26.spl.out";
print $cmd,"\n";
system($cmd);
chdir($curdir);
```

Comment: Thank you ,i finally install the rouge on linux .and i can run that.

Answer (score 5):

> the system can't find the specified path

You have wrong path to your script, `/ROUGE-1.5.5.pl` does not exists, and thus shell invoked by `system()` is complaining.

Comment: (More specifically, the shell launched by `system` is complaining.)

Comment: @ikegami tnx for comment

Comment: thank you ,but my ROUGE-1.5.5.pl is in the current folder that this program exist

Comment: @EhsanAkbar try `$ROUGE="../ROUGE-1.5.5.pl";` or `$ROUGE="./ROUGE-1.5.5.pl";` then since you're switching directories

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that `/ROUGE-1.5.5.pl` is an *absolute* file path that says the file is in the root directory. You say it is in the same directory as the running Perl program so you need `./ROUGE-1.5.5.pl` or just `ROUGE-1.5.5.pl`

This program fixes the problem and plugs a few holes. I have used the `abs_path` function from `Cwd` to convert the program, data, input and output names to absolute paths; that performs an implicit check that the files exist, and lets me avoid the `chdir` which just confuses things. I've also added a crude diagnostic to `system` to give some hint why it failed

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Cwd qw/ getcwd abs_path /;

my $ROUGE  = abs_path('ROUGE-1.5.5.pl');

my $data   = abs_path('data');
my $input  = abs_path('sample-test/DUC2002ROUGE.in.26.spl.xm');
my $output = abs_path('sample-output/salam.out');

my $cmd = qq{"$ROUGE" -e "$data" -c 95 -2 -1 -U -r 1000 -n 4 -w 1.2 -a "$input" > "$output"};
print $cmd, "\n";

system($cmd) == 0 or die qq{system() failed: $?};
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe I have the answer if you want the ROUGE output to be stored in a file rather than printed to the command line or terminal.

You don't need a perl script, you can run ROUGE from the command line. To output to a file add `> results.txt` to the end of the command.

Running something like this will output to the command line:

```
perl ROUGE-1.5.5.pl -e data -n 4 -w 1.2 -m  -2 4 -u -c 95 -r 1000 -f A -p 0.5 -t 0 -a -d settings.xml
```

Whereas this will output to a file called results.txt:

```
perl ROUGE-1.5.5.pl -e data -n 4 -w 1.2 -m  -2 4 -u -c 95 -r 1000 -f A -p 0.5 -t 0 -a -d settings.xml > results.txt
```

This question helped me: [How to redirect console output to a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10682087/how-to-redirect-console-output-to-a-text-file)

Answer (score 2):

You had a few wrong file paths and a couple of typos but this works:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use Cwd;
$curdir=getcwd;
$ROUGE="../ROUGE-1.5.5.pl";
chdir("sample-test");
$cmd="$ROUGE -e ../data -c 95 -2 -1 -U -r 1000 -n 4 -w 1.2 -a DUC2002-ROUGE.in.26.spl.xml > ../sample-output/salam.out";
print $cmd,"\n";
system($cmd);
chdir($curdir);
```

But why use a perl to script to run ROUGE when you could just type this into the command line:

`perl ROUGE-1.5.5.pl -e data -c 95 -2 -1 -U -r 1000 -n 4 -w 1.2 -a sample-test/DUC2002-ROUGE.in.26.spl.xml > sample-output/salam.out`

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the other answers regarding absolute vs. relative paths.  I also agree with the issue of why use Perl when you can do this as a simple command line argument.  However, I'm going to turn that around and say, if you are going to use Perl to do this, make it an opportunity to document what you're doing to make it easier to tweak in the future, something like:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Cwd;

my $curdir = getcwd;

use constant ROUGE => '../ROUGE-1.5.5.pl';

my @OPTIONS = ('-2', '-1', '-U', # use skip-bigrams and compute unigram scores (not sure -1 is valid)
    '-e' => '../data', # data directory
    '-c' => 95, # confidence interval (default)
    '-r' => 1000, # sampling points (default)
    '-n' => 4, # max-ngram length
    '-w' => 1.2, # LCS weight
    '-a' => 'DUC2002-ROUGE.in.26.spl.xml'
);

if (chdir("sample-test")) {

    my $cmd = join(" ", ROUGE, @OPTIONS, "> ../sample-output/salam.out");
    print STDERR $cmd, "\n";
    system($cmd);

    chdir($curdir);
}
```

Answer (score -4):

1. install perl 
   http://www.activestate.com/activeperl
2. run from dos command if on windows

   perl perlscript.pl

Comment: Why the -1, the question was incapeble to run the program.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but the error message quoted in the question was emitted when the script ran - so the user must have had Perl installed already.  Also I'd recommend Strawberry Perl over ActivePerl.