# How to print the output of seaching a string from a no of files to a output File In Perl

Tags: perl

I have the following code and I want the output to .txt file so can someone pls help to print the output Into some file ?
Rather It should have an option for a user to push to file or print to the command prompt Itself.

```
# Opening Keyword File here
open( my $kw, '<', 'IMSRegistration_Success_MessageFlow.txt') or die $!;
my @keywords = <$kw>;
chomp(@keywords); # remove newlines at the end of keywords

# post-processing your keywords file for adding comments
my $kwhashref = {
  map {
    /^(.*?)(#.*?#)*$/;
    defined($2) ? ($1 => $2) : ( $1 => undef )
  } @keywords
}; 

# get list of files in current directory
my @files = grep { -f } (<*main_log>,<*Project>,<*properties>);
# loop over each file to search keywords in
foreach my $file (@files) 
{
    open(my $fh, '<', $file) or die $!;
    my @content = <$fh>;
    close($fh);
    my $l = 0;

    foreach my $kw (keys %$kwhashref) 
    {
        my $search = quotemeta($kw); # otherwise keyword is used as regex, not literally
        foreach (@content) 
            { # go through every line for this keyword
                $l++;
                if (/$search/)
                    {
                        print $kwhashref->{$kw}."\n" if defined($kwhashref->{$kw}) ;
                        printf 'Found keyword %s in file %s, line %d:%s'.$/, $kw, $file, $l, $_
                    }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried to do yourself, and what problem did you encounter? We can't help you very easily if you don't describe what went wrong.

Comment: `print $fh ...` and `printf $fh ...`, but it's more flexible to just lest the caller redirect the output (`script.pl >output.txt`)

Comment: when I use the command perl Test.pl > my_output.txt I can get the output Into my file outout.txt but i want to Incorporate It within the script . something like using the system command.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907593/how-can-i-redirect-standard-output-to-a-file-in-perl check the second answer of this question

Comment: That's quite complicated code, given that this question is about writing to a file. Did you write it and are you having problems modifying it, or ... is it someone else's code that you're asking the internet to fix?

Comment: @John Doe .. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
script.pl >output.txt
```

Comment: I can use from the command prompt but I want to Incorporate It Within the Script Itself. e.g. using some system() commands etc.

Answer (score 0):

I can get the output Into a file using below code:

print $out_file $kwhashref->{$kw}."\n" if defined($kwhashref->{$kw}) ;
printf $out_file 'Found keyword %s in file %s, line %d:%s'.$/, $kw, $file, $l, $_;