# How do I send multi-line output from Perl to /bin/mail?

Tags: perl, smtp, module, client, stdout

I have a Perl script that prints multiple lines of output to screen. I need to capture those lines and either pipe them into a single piece of email ( /bin/mail ) or into a text file that I can send by /bin mail in another operation. Actually, I have already figured out the easy (dumb) way whereby I use a bash wrapper to do the mailing bit. Looks like,

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
source /nethome/zog/.bash_profile 
cd /nethome/zog/bin/perl  
/nethome/zog/bin/perl/find_free_space.pl > text.file
/bin/mail -s FreeSpace@NJ3 zog@geemail.com < text.file
```

I want to be using Net::SMTP to do the smtp bit. The above is inelegant, to say the least.

I saw something like this:

```
open(MAIL, "| /bin/mail -s FreePorts me\@geemail.com") || 
   die "mail failed: $!\n"; print MAIL "This is how it goes."
```

on stackoverflow but failed to redirect the STDOUT into mail. I'm using:

```
$complete_output .= "\n"; "|/bin/mail -s FreePorts zog\@geeemail.com" || die "mail failed: $!\n";
```

I'm not sure if you all need to see the Perl script in order to help, but [it is on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/s0wRyaS0). Please let me know.

Comment: you came pretty close, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/655719/how-do-i-unalias-from-perls-stdout

Answer (score 1):

STDOUT isn't in play here. Is there something you forgot to tell us? What happened when you printed to the `MAIL` filehandle? Did that output make it into the message? What happens when you send multiple lines to the `MAIL` filehandle?

Your code is:

```
"|/bin/mail -s FreePorts zog\@geeemail.com" || die "mail failed: $!\n";
```

That does nothing. It's a string, which is also a true value. The alternation never does to the die branch. What happened when you used the first bit of code in your question? Write a small example script to see if you can send mail and test with that until you figure it out. For example, this is a complete script that tests your problem:

```
#!perl
use strict;
use warnings;
open my $mail, '| /bin/mail -s FreePorts me@geemail.com';
print $mail "This is a test message from $$ at " . localtime() . "\n";
close $mail or die "The pipe failed!\n $?";
```

What happens when you run that? What happens when you try that same command from the command line?

Why not use a Perl module (like one of the Email::* modules) instead of relying on an external command? There's a lot to know about interprocess communication, and I think you're behind the curve on that. A module takes care of all of the details for you, has a nicer interface, and is more flexible.

Comment: }
        #print "\n";
        $complete_output .= "\n"; "|/bin/mail -s FreePorts zog\@gmeeil.com" || die "mail failed: $!\n";
}

Comment: I have what I think is a global scalar named, "$complete_output" in this script that collects all the lines of output. This works. Now I need to be able to send that collected data into /bin/mail or /usr/sbin/sendmail

Comment: Edit your question with additional details. Show us a complete example script that demonstrates the problem you're having.

Comment: Reduce your program to the smallest script that demonstrates the problem and add it to your answer to it's always with StackOverflow.